# MongoDB: upsert sub document array

Tags: mongodb, upsert, subdocument

I have the following 'SaleOrderCol' collection:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('1000'),
  products: [
              { _id: ObjectId('1001'), name: 'ProdA', qty: 5},
              { _id: ObjectId('1002'), name: 'ProdB', qty: 10}
            ]
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('2000'),
  products: [
              { _id: ObjectId('2001'), name: 'ProdA', qty: 5},
              { _id: ObjectId('2002'), name: 'ProdC', qty: 10}
            ]
}
```

I want to do an upsert to change name and qty of subdocument (1002) and try below:

```
SaleOrderCol.updateOne(
    { 
      "_id": ObjectId('1000'),
      "products._id": ObjectId('1002')
    },
    {
      $set : { "products": { name: 'ProdBB', qty: 15 }
    },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

It throws error. How to get it to work? Thank you

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: I realised that my question above is oversimplify to become a duplicate (as indicated by Neil Lunn). In my actual case, I actually have a subdocument resided within a subarray. However, with similar positional operator $ hint, I am able to resolve. So will close this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$` positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])

For example:

```
updateOne({ 
      "_id": ObjectId('1000'),
      "products._id": ObjectId('1002')
    },{
       $set: {"products.$.name": 'ProdBB' } // include other fields here
   });
);
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks jakemingolia.